# Shiny capture traceback on disconnect / crash

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to capture when a shiny application crashes/disconnects (i.e.: closes WebSocket connection) along with its traceback ~ message.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("crash", "Crash")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  onStop(function(){
    print(warnings()) # nothing
    print(traceback()) # NULL
    print(shiny:::.globals$deepStack) # NULL
  })

  session$onEnded(function(){
    print(warnings()) # nothing
    print(traceback()) # NULL
    print(shiny:::.globals$deepStack) # NULL
  })
 
  observeEvent(input$crash, {
    print(error) # no error object: disconnects
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Also on [RS Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-capture-crash-disconnect/151688/9)

Comment: In general, whatever process is "serving" your app typically has a log associated with it; Connect, for example, produces files `job.stdout` and `job.stderr` for each app/session, located under `.../jobs/<appid>/<anotherid>/`, and those files often contain some context as to what may have caused the app to stop, fail, and/or crash.

Comment: I'd like to second @r2evans comment. This is basically what I was showing in my related answer [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-devmode-and-writing-logs-sink/143106/2).

Comment: RSC is not serving the applications. RStudio Connect merely runs `runApp`, R, shiny, via httpuv serves the app, Connect is a load balancer not a server.
We can always parse log files but that's not how one recovers or handles errors.

Comment: Without shiny being modified ([FR](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3677)), currently I don't see any other solution. Either you catch the error before shiny's error handling does (e.g. wrapping critical code in `tryCatch`) or you parse stdout/stderr of the process running the shiny app (could be done with a global `reactiveFileReader` pointing on the logfile). For sure a built-in solution offering the traceback would be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this isn't what @JohnCoene is searching for - Here you can find examples regarding my above comment.

*First approach* - Read stdout/stderr from logfile via cross-session `reactiveFileReader` (`library(callr)` is used only to provide a reproducible example, the logfile might already be available as mentioned by @r2evans):

```
library(shiny)
library(callr)

# devmode()

if(!file.exists("shinyapp.log")){
  file.create("shinyapp.log") 
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("shinyapp_log_out"),
  actionButton("error", "Crash session"),
  actionButton("stop_app", "Stop app")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  session$onEnded(function(){
    print(paste("Session:", session$token, "ended."))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$error, {
    1*"a"
  })
  observeEvent(input$stop_app, {
    stopApp()
  })
  output$shinyapp_log_out <- renderText({c("Session token:", session$token, "\n", shinyapp_log())}, sep = "\n")
}

app <- shinyApp(ui, server,
                onStart = function() {
                  cat("Doing application setup\n")
                  shinyapp_log <<- reactiveFileReader(1000, session = NULL, filePath = "shinyapp.log", readFunc = function(x){crayon::strip_style(paste0(readLines(x), collapse = "\n"))})
                  onStop(function() {
                    cat("Doing application cleanup\n")
                  })
                })

shinyapp_process <- r_bg(function(app){
  shiny::runApp(
    appDir = app,
    port = 80,
    launch.browser = FALSE,
    host = "0.0.0.0"
  )}, args = list(app), supervise = TRUE, stdout = "shinyapp.log", stderr = "2>&1") # , stdout = "", stderr = "2>&1"

browseURL("http://127.0.0.1/")

# shinyapp_process$is_alive()
# shinyapp_process$get_pid()
# shinyapp_process$kill()
```

[image: result]

---

*Second approach* - catch error before shiny's error handler does:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(actionButton("crash", "Try to crash session"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$crash, {
    tryCatch({
      print(error) # wrap critical code
    }, error = function(e) {
      cat("Handling error:\n", paste(e, collapse = "\n"))
    }, warning = function(w) {
      cat("Handling warning:\n", paste(w, collapse = "\n"))
    }, finally = {
      cat("tryCatch done\n")
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.

I just think this is far too complex and a more elegant solution should be provided. I have made a [PR](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/3724) we'll see whether it gets merged or what the maintainers or RStudio come back with.

Comment: I completely agree with you - it should be much easier. Thanks for pointing to your PR.